# Angular: Signal application update to browser

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app. If I run it in the dev-server all is fine.

If I make a prod version and copy the files of dist into the webservers public directory then the browser does not load the new version - even if I refresh the page.

I am using Firefox, webserver is Apache2. If I clean my browser cache it will load the new version correctly.

How can I signal the browser to reload the new version instead of using the cached one?

Comment: Do you build with an `--output-hashing=none` ?

Comment: I did not set that. Should I set it to none or to all?

Comment: `all` which is the default value if you build with the `--prod` option.

Answer (score 1):

you can append a version query parameter to the files when you include them in the index.html and increase it with each new build.

when the browser finds that the query string parameters are changed then it is forced to retrieve the file from the server again

it would be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?ver=1"></script>
```

Comment: Whilst this is true, and useful in a lot of circumstances, Angular by default adds a hash to the name of the files, which is a better technique than query string params as there are systems that ignore query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to be configured to send the appropriate cache control headers. If you don't have control over the server configuration, you can also look at adding meta tags to index.html

A prod build of an Angular application should result in js files with new hashes, which should allow the end user to get a new version. However it could be that caching is set up in a way that it won't get the changes.
[Adding meta tags to the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) and [setting up the server correctly](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/glossary/cache-control.html) should fix the issue.